# How consume again uncommitted message from kafka partition in same connection

Tags: go, apache-kafka, franz-go

I am using client library [franz-go](https://github.com/twmb/franz-go)  for kafka .
I'm trying to consume the same message for the second time in the same connection .

First of all I produce some message to topic, then I consume this message but don't commit them.

I want to consume again this message without reconecting (when I reconnect, I can consume this message again)

Is there any way to get this message again?
Case with reconnect works correctly and I get the same message second time

```golang
package main

import (
    "context"
    "github.com/twmb/franz-go/pkg/kgo"
)

func main() {
    cl, err := kgo.NewClient(
        kgo.SeedBrokers("localhost:9092"),
        kgo.ConsumerGroup("some_consumer_group"),
        kgo.ConsumeTopics("topic"),
        kgo.DefaultProduceTopic("topic"),
        kgo.DisableAutoCommit(),
    )
    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }
    record := &kgo.Record{
        Key:   []byte("some_key"),
        Value: []byte("some value"),
    }

    ctx := context.Background()
    produceResult := cl.ProduceSync(ctx, record)
    if produceResult.FirstErr() != nil {
        panic(err)
    }

    fetches := cl.PollFetches(ctx)
    if fetches.Err() != nil {
        panic(err)
    }
    //I don't commit
    doSomething(fetches)

    //after that I want to get the same message again and handle it again
    //but here I'm faced with endless waiting
    fetches = cl.PollFetches(ctx)
    if fetches.Err() != nil {
        panic(err)
    }
    doSomething(fetches)
    err = cl.CommitRecords(ctx, fetches.Records()...)
    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }

}

func doSomething(result kgo.Fetches) {
    // I do something with kafka messages
    // and something went wrong
}
```

Comment: How about using 2 consumer group names's to consume the messages twice?

Comment: What to do if second consumer group failed to process messages and we don't want to commit again? Create third, fourth etc... consumer group? :DDD

Comment: Other Kafka libraries have a Seek function exactly for this. I don't know about franz